# MUP Deployed Site Not Displaying After Update

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I used Meteor Up (MUP) to deploy my meteor app to a Digital Ocean droplet. I had some problems with deploying it the first time but I solved all of them and I got it working. I then made some updates to my app but when I deployed it again the page says "This webpage is not available". I have tried re-deploying the app on new droplets with different IP addresses but the same happens. I have run `mup setup` on each new droplet. It always says success for the setup and for the deployment but nothing shows up.

Can anybody tell me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there is some kind of error with your app, probably not related to deployment if it the issue occurs in the way your describe it.

You'll have to check your app's server side logs for a bit more info:

```
mup logs -f
```

Comment: i have run `mup logs -f` but it gets stuck at: `>> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser`

Comment: I am having the same issue